# Seaborn: overlay scatterplot on top of boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, boxplot

I want to overlay a simple scatterplot on top of my boxplot. When I plot the two plots separately, everything is fine:

[image: boxplot solo]
[image: scatterplot solo]

But when I try to combine them, it almost looks like x-values of the scatterplot are all being divided by 2:

[image: together]

I'm pretty sure it's because the boxplot treats the x-axis values as categorical (even though they are floats in my DataFrame), while the scatterplot treats them as continuous. But I don't know what the solution is. Here is the code I am using:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=old_data, x="x-axis", y="y-axis", s=200, color="red", label="Old Data")
sns.boxplot(data=new_data, x="x-axis", y="y-axis", color="blue")
plt.plot([], [], label="New Data", color='blue') # this just adds the boxplot label to the legend
plt.legend()
```

**Bonus question:** if you know how to add the boxplot label to the legend in a better way, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: For the boxplot, the `x` is considered categorical, while for the scatter plot the `x` is considered numeric. Converting the `x` to string would also make the scatter plot categorical. So `old_data['x_axis'] = old_data['x_axis'].astype(str)`.

Comment: Hey @JohanC, thanks that worked for me!